# Ndarray dtype multidimensional array - how to choose the first element of each array element?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have an multidimensional ndarray of tuples, which further consists of two elements - first is another array and second is a dict. I am after the first element of each of these tuples. Basically make another array with the same shape, but with the first element of each of the tuples. Here is an example data structure:

```
a = np.array([[( ([1,2], [3,4]), {"a":1}), (([12,243], [30,40]), {"d":1})],
              [(([32,24], [3,4]), {"b":1}), (([13,22], [320, 30]), {"c":1})]], dtype=object)
```

And I need the following array from `a`:

```
b  = np.array([[[1,2], [12, 243]], 
               [[32, 24], [13, 22]]])
```

I know this can be done using nested for loops, but I want to avoid that as it can have more than 2 dimensions. I also tried using nditer, but I kept getting errors and was not sure how to go about it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is one way to go about it:

```
b = np.empty_like(a[..., 0])

for index, i in np.ndenumerate(a[..., 0]):
    b[index] = i[0]
```

But, is this the most efficient way? I am not sure, as I want this to work for very large arrays.

EDIT: Sorry, my bad. There is another complication that I did not add. The first element of each of that tuple is another tuple. I just updated it.

Second Edit: Added a way using the for loop to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

I updated all code according to `new input`:

**Snippet:**

```
data1 = np.stack(a[..., 0]).tolist()
data = np.array(data1)
output = data[:, :, 0]
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[( ([1,2], [3,4]), {"a":1}), (([12,243], [30,40]), {"d":1})],
               [(([32,24], [3,4]), {"b":1}), (([13,22], [320, 30]), {"c":1})]], dtype=object)

data1 = np.stack(a[..., 0]).tolist()
data = np.array(data1)
output = data[:, :, 0]

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[  1   2]
  [ 12 243]]

 [[ 32  24]
  [ 13  22]]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question. Could you please take a look at it again?

Comment: @lattitude I updated the code according to ur new input.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This works fine when a is 2D. But, I can have an n dimensional array for a, and I would like to get the same output regardless of the dimension of a.

Comment: @lattitude I updated the code again without using for loops.. maybe it gives hint..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that they are lists inside numpy arrays, and you want to cast them to numpy arrays. You can do this:

```
b = np.array(a[..., 0].tolist())
```

Note that `a[..., 0]` returns a 2-dimensional array of  lists. `.tolist` will convert it to a 3-dimensional Python list, and then `np.array` will cast it to a 3-dimensional numpy array of ints.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question. Could you please take a look at it again?

Comment: The answer is basically the same, but getting only the first values of the first tuples : b = np.array(a[..., 0].tolist())[..., 0, :]